# Android: Giving ID's to Dynamically created Edit Texts

Tags: android, layout

I have a following layout that is generated dynamically on `Add Button`

**rowdetail.xml**

```
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/editText"/>

        <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="0.2">

        </View>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/editText1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OnClick()**

```
final LinearLayout newView = (LinearLayout)activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowdetail, null);
                newView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                linearLayoutForm.addView(newView);
```

How do I give ID's to the Edit Texts? 
All the `EditText` on left side will have one set of `id` and the right side will havee another set of `id`.

Example

```
 EditTextLeft1     EditTextRight1 
 EditTextLeft2     EditTextRight2 
 EditTextLeft3     EditTextRight3 
 EditTextLeft4     EditTextRight4
```

Comment: Do you know how many EditTexts are going to be created dynamically?

Comment: max 8 -15 EditTextLeft and same no. EditTextRight

Comment: Well, i have a small theory in my mind. If you're sure about the number of edittexts that are gonna be created dynamically, why don't you put that number of IDs in an array and use a counter to identify that last ID used. Then set the ID of the edittext using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dynamic object names ... try this way

```
for(int i=0;i<buttonCount;i++){
    EditText editText = new EditText(context);
    editText.setId(i+1);
}
```

later you can use `editText.getId()` to identify the instance...